# Python how to merge two dataframes with multiple columns while preserving row order in each column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, merge

My data is contained within two dataframes. Within each dataframe, the entries are sorted in each column. I want to now merge the two dataframes while preserving row order. For example, suppose I have this:

The first dataframe "A1" looks like this:

```
index  a   b   c   
0      1   4   1
3      2   7   3
5      5   8   4
6      6   10  8
...
```

and the second dataframe "A2" looks like this (A1 and A2 are the same size):

```
index  a   b   c
1      3   1   2
2      4   2   5
4      7   3   6
7      8   5   7
...
```

I want to merge both of these dataframes to get the final dataframe "data":

```
index  a   b   c
0      1   4   1
1      3   1   2
2      4   2   5
3      2   7   3  
...
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
data = A1.merge(A2, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

But I keep getting strange results. I don't even know if this works if you have multiple columns whose row order you need to preserve. I find that some of the entries become NaNs for some reason. I don't know how to fix it. I also tried data.join(A1, A2) but the compiler printed out that it couldn't join these two dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

#Create Data Frame df and df1
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[5,6,7,8],'c':[9,0,11,12]},index=[0,3,5,6])
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[13,14,15,16],'b':[17,18,19,20],'c':[21,22,23,24]},index=[1,2,4,7])

#Append df and df1 and sort by index.
df2 = df.append(df1)
print(df2.sort_index())
```